# Write an Openrewrite java recipe test ignoring compilation errors

Tags: openrewrite

Is it possible to write an Openrewrite java recipe test ignoring compilation errors due to unknown class types not included in `JavaParser` classpath?

Example:

```java
    @Test
    void requiredRequestParam() {

        rewriteRun(
                spec -> spec
                        .recipe(new MandatoryRequestParameter())
                        .parser(JavaParser.fromJavaVersion().classpath("spring-web")),
                java(
                        """
                          import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
                          
                          class ControllerClass {
                            public String sayHello (
                              @RequestParam(value = "fred") String fred,
                              @RequestParam(value = "lang") String lang,
                              @RequestParam(value = "aNumber") Long aNumber
                            ) {
                              return "Hello";
                            }
                          }
                        """,
                        """
                          import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
                          
                          class ControllerClass {
                            public String sayHello (
                              @RequestParam(required = true, value = "fred") String fred,
                              @RequestParam(value = "lang") String lang,
                              @RequestParam(required = true, value = "aNumber") Long aNumber
                            ) {
                              return "Hello";
                            }
                          }
                        """
                )
        );
    }
```

In this case, `spring-web` artifact must be included in test classpath for the `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam` type to be recognized.

Comment: Hi José! Why would you want to ignore compilation errors as opposed to making the required types available in the test? You're already adding the `.classpath("spring-web")`; does that not work for you as expected?

There's a good chance your recipe will not work as expected when there are unresolvable types, as we back off from making changes when we can not be certain that we can make changes without issues. If the `RequestParam` type is not available for instance, your `MandatoryRequestParameter` recipe will likely not match any `RequestParam` annotations.

Comment: Hi @Tim

We develop a large company framework (lot of modules and third party dependencies) and we want to create a recipe library for some migrations. It seems strange to me that we need to declare every single dependency in our recipe library pom just because of this. We thought we could write recipe tests only with initial LST and final LST without strict type or compilation checks.

Comment: Well we are moving towards a model where you can define a subset of transformations by matching a lossless semantic sub tree with a lambda, and then also defining the replacement as a lambda. That makes it easier to define such replacements, but definitely would require the original and replacement types to be on the classpath. Happy to talk through the options for your use case some more; are you already in our Slack as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `typeValidationOptions()` on the `RecipeSpec` for this purpose (see example below). To disable all type checks you can call `typeValidationOptions(TypeValidation.none())` and to be more fine-grained, `TypeValidation` provides a builder API to disable specific type checks.

As pointed out by Tim however, you would normally want to configure the recipe classpath (using either `JavaParser#classpath()` or `JavaParser#classpathFromResources()`, see [docs for details](https://docs.openrewrite.org/concepts-and-explanations/javatemplate#referencing-external-types)) so that you don't get any type validation errors. Disabling type validation errors can still be necessary in some situations (e.g. when you want to check that your recipe also does something useful in the presence of type errors).

```java
    @Test
    void requiredRequestParam() {
        rewriteRun(
                spec -> spec
                        .recipe(new MandatoryRequestParameter())
                        .parser(JavaParser.fromJavaVersion().classpath("spring-web"))
                        .typeValidationOptions(TypeValidation.none()),
                java(
                    // ...
                )
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @knutwannheden.

We develop a company framework and we want to create a custom recipe library for some migrations. I was surprised I had to include all types declared in a recipe test in the test classpath because that way I will have to include a lot of dependencies in our recipe library pom.xml, and I don't understand why. I thought we could only change from one LST to another without requiring code to actually resolve types.

`.typeValidationOptions(TypeValidation.none())` didn't work for me. Will fill an issue on Openrewrite github repo in order to clarify.

Comment: You could also use `JavaParser.fromJavaVersion().classpath(JavaParser.runtimeClasspath())` if you want the Java sources in your tests to be able to refer to any types available on the test classpath.

The types are required on the classpath so that the LST can be fully type-attributed. This in turn is necessary for many recipes to work properly, as they frequently check what types the sources refer to. Hope this helps to clarify.

Comment: Thanks @knutwannheden

Also posted this question to clarify: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/issues/3129